# Line of polynomial regression doesnt appear

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

So i m building a polynomial regression because before i built a regression line and eventhough it was very good i wanted to improve it since my scatter plot with my data set was forming half of a Parabolic. So i wanted to test it and see if it would beat my R squared value for my regression line. So i came to this code snippet:

```
from numpy import arange
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define the true objective function
def objective(x, a, b, c):
 return a * x + b * x**2 + c
 
# load the dataset
data = abalone_df.values

# choose the input and output variables
x, y = data[:, 1], data[:, 4]
# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
# summarize the parameter values
a, b, c = popt
print(a,b,c)
print('y = %.5f * x + %.5f * x^2 + %.5f' % (a, b, c))
# plot input vs output
plt.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
plt.plot(x_line, y_line, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

When the graphics appears, it's missing the polynomial line that best fit my data set and i cant seem to know why and i tried other approaches in which one was right but since my R squared value was so low i assumed something was also wrong regarding it. I need some help here

Here's the data stored in x and y respectively:

> [0.455 0.35 0.53 ... 0.6 0.625 0.71] [0.514 0.2255 0.677 ... 1.176 1.0945 1.9485]

I can't provide all because i have 4177 instances

Comment: Check the contents of `x_line`. Is it a single point? That can happen depending on `x`. For example, `np.arange(0.1, 0.9, 1)` has a single element, `0.1`. Try `np.linspace` instead. It'd be best if you could provide `x` and `y` for us so we can rule out this possibility.

Comment: are you trying to exactly match the objective function using curve fitting?

Comment: Without the data, we cannot test your code to see what's wrong.

Comment: I can't provide all the data since i m working with a dataframe with 4177 instances but i can provide some of it. If u want the actual data its [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/1/abalone). And yes i m trying to match it.

Comment: Also yes my x_line contains a single entry @K.Cl

Comment: Okay so i did some digging and i realized that i defined 1 as a step with very small numbers. I changed it to 0.001 and it finally appeared. Should i close my question?

Comment: So you had set the step size of `np.arange` to something too large? In the future, you can use `np.linspace` instead, where instead of specifying the stepsize you specify the total number of points. And if your question is answered then yes, you can close the question.

Comment: Yeah pretty much it, i will look forward to it thank you